# jenkins-x - jx boot failing with 'Error creating bucket'

Tags: jenkins

while running from local laptop jx boot, it creates buckets on GoogleCloud:

```
....
....
The bucket gs://acmecluster1-logs-1ed782b2-db25-4631-bbf7-7a2178eec2a6 does not exist so lets create it
The bucket gs://acmecluster1-reports-4836f7b2-4f55-435d-9087-619c54d469 does not exist so lets create it
The bucket gs://acmecluster1-repository-60a6f654-7cd4-4027-9d23-1b81577 does not exist so lets create it
....
....
```

Later on, after

```
    ....
    ....
    vault-operator addon succesfully installed.
    vault operator installed in namespace jx
    finding vault in namespace jx
    Creating new system vault
    Updated property [core/project].
    Service Account exists
    Downloading service account key
    Error creating bucket: Creating gs://jx-vault-acmecluster1-bucket/...
ServiceException: 409 Bucket jx-vault-acmecluster1-bucket already exists., failed to run 'gsutil mb -l us-west1 -p acmecorp-one gs://jx-vault-acmecluster1-bucket' command in directory '', output: 'Creating gs://jx-vault-acmecluster1-bucket/...
```

it fails, trying to create another storage. The error message 'already exists' is probably false, least after terminating the run there is no such bucket. Some clue how to go around this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried removing the previous storage bucket?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seem to be the name of the bucket jenkins-x is trying to create. `gs://jx-vault-acmecluster1-bucket` needs to be unique on Google (probably a bug in jenkins-x).

If you check the other created buckets they have an autogenerated uuid `gs://acmecluster1-repository-60a6f654-7cd4-4027-9d23-1b81577`.

For now what I suggest is to change the name of your cluster/organization to avoid this issue for now.

EDIT: You can also fix this changing the name of the vault in jx-requirements.yml

```
vault:
  name: xxxxxxx #something unique
```